# Keep track whether text file has or has not certain symbol

Tags: python

I have a series text files which are pages from books. (Think of this as a series of text files in a directory). Each text file has several lines of text. My task is to search through the entire text file for a special character, in this case '#'.

I would like a program to search through the entire page, and record whether this page has '#' or doesn't have '#'. The output `results` should be a list which states the specific page and whether '#' exists.

```
page1 yes
page2 no
page3 no
```

My problem: I don't know how to keep track which file/page has '#' and which doesn't.

```
hashkeylist = []

for page in book:
    for line in page:
        for x in line:
            if x == '#':
                hashkeylist.append(x)
            else:
                pass

results = []

for i in range(len(book)): # range of number of pages to label pages
    if '#' in hashkeylist:
        results.append('page %d yes' % (d)) 
    else:
        results.append('page %d no' % (d))
```

Obviously, this doesn't work at all.

How does one keep track which page has a hashkey symbol, and which page doesn't?

Comment: Is your `book` a list, and there's a lot of lists (also there's a lot of lists in these lists) in it?

Comment: @KevinGuan There is no book. There are dozens of text files, each text file is a block of text.

Comment: @ShanZhengYang, you can check each file as per my answer, you don't need to store any lines in memory and you should short circuit once you get a match as there is no point looking when you have already found it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, list all the text files in `file_list` list variable and then iterate. Below is just a sample code. Please try if it helps for you.

```
file_list = []
results = []
for filename in file_list:
    with open(filename, "r") as fileobj:
        if "#" in fileobj.read():
            results.append("%s Yes" % filename)
        else:
            results.append("%s No" % filename)

for item in results:
    print item
```

Answer (score 1):

*Think of this as a series of text files in a directory). Each text file has several lines of text*

This is trivial to solve, loop over each file using two lists, one for files that do have the symbol and one for those that don't, use `any` to see if any line contains the symbol which will short circuit on  a match, there is no need to read or store all the lines at once:

```
 has, has_not = [],[]
 for fle in files:
    with open(fle) as f:
        if any("#" in line for line in f):
                has.append(fle)
        else:
            has_not.append(fle)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping through each line and search the characters individual letters. When you open the text file, simply do:

```
f.read().find('#')
```

If `f` is your file object, it will return `-1` if the symbol is not found anywhere in the text, otherwise it will return the index of the first occurrence of the character.

To keep track of the files **with** the symbol, you can use the line of code above as a condition, and if it returns anything other than `-1` add the name of the currently opened file to a list for later use.

```
l = list()
l.append(f.name) # name is a class variable for file objects that is preset
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I think this should works:

```
results = []

for num, page in enumerate(book, start=1):
    if '#' in '\n'.join(page):
        results.append('page{} yes'.format(num))
    else:
        results.append('page{} no'.format(num))
```

Since your code looks like `page` is a list, and there's some **lines** in that list. If `page` is string and not a list, then you don't need `'\n'.join(page)`, just use `if '#' in page:` instead.

Or, one-line version:

```
results = ['page{0} {1}'.format(num, 'yes' if '#' in '\n'.join(page) else 'no') for num, page in enumerate(book, start=1)]
```

Comment: The conditional block can also be simplified in another way. `existence = ('no', 'yes')` and you get the relevant string with `existence['#' in page]` which can be passed straight to the format.

Comment: @Reti43: I know and tried, that doesn't clear, and only less 7 letters.